# no callback function in cross domain json file

Tags: jsonp

i'm trying to use cross domain jsonp. i have done this before using the callback function in the json file from the other domain. i'm looking at an example json data file that google uses in one of its tutorials:

http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/geojsonp/2.5/week -- here obviously the callback function here is `eqfeed_callback`. in the json file i'm trying to use, there is no callback function that kicks everything off, there is just a bracket `[`. the file starts off like:

```
[{"Address":"4441 Van Nuys Blvd","City":"Sherman Oaks" ...
```

and ends like:

```
}]
```

what should i do? is there another way to get at the data without a callback function? i can't edit this file. it's a service that i have a subscription to.

thx.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not your server, and the server doesn't support JSONP, there's no way you can force it to return jsonp. You could try adding `?callback=callback` to your url to see if that convinces the server to wrap it in a callback, but if it doesn't, you're out of luck.

Well, almost. There is actually a really dirty hack that you shouldn't use, which is to override javascript's standard Array constructor to assign the contents of the array to a global variable. But that's pretty hideous and I strongly advise against it.

Better ask the maintainer of the service if they're willing to support JSONP. Or better yet, add a CORS header.